# wp_dropdown_pages tax_query clause

Tags: wordpress

I'm display a dropdown list of custom post types in wordpress. This first block of code uses WP_Query

```
$houseQuery = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'house',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'title',
        'nopaging' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'teamtype',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => 'sectorteam', // exclude house posts in the sectorteam custom teamtype taxonomy
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN')
        ))
);
if( $companyList->have_posts() ) :
    while ($companyList->have_posts()) : $houseQuery->the_post();
        if(get_the_ID()==$c)
            $name=$post->post_title;
        echo '{ value:'.get_the_ID().', label: "'.get_the_title(get_the_ID()).'"},';
    endwhile;
endif;
```

This is the second cut of the code which uses 'wp_dropdown_page()' method and is a bit more concise

```
$args = array (
    'id' => 'house',
    'name' => 'house',
    'echo' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'house'
);
wp_dropdown_pages($args);
```

I need to exclude the posts defined by the 'tax_query' in the first example but am ensure how this can be done with the arguments that 'wp_dropdown_pages' uses, any ideas?

Comment: You might consider posting this to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: i did as well, but i find stackoverflow gets better replies

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `exlude` or `exclude_tree` parameters as [described in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages)?

> **Exclude**
>   Comma separated list of category IDs to exclude. For example, 'exclude=4,12' means category IDs 4 and 12 will NOT be displayed/echoed or returned. Defaults to exclude nothing.

Since you're using `post_type` parameter I assume your custom post type is hierarchical.

Comment: I did try the exclude but the documentation says this applies to a category and not a taxonomy

Comment: `wp_dropdown_pages` is calling `get_pages` to fetch items, so [all of its parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) should work. Is your post type hierarchical?

Comment: yes it's hierarchical. i was thinking i could move all the posts in the specific taxonomy to a specific parent post, and then exclude it but it seems a bit of a hack.